# Rails 4: Notifications by user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm using action cable to create notifications in my app. The notifications area was created based on [this tutorial](https://www.onehub.com/blog/2016/02/18/event-notifications-in-rails-5-with-actioncable/). The question is: how can I divide the notifications by user? so that the notifications are sent to each user individually. I'm using rails 4.2.6 with `gem 'actioncable'`

I'm also getting this error in the route `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'` when I try to run the server:

> /config/routes.rb:9:in `block in ': uninitialized
>   constant ActionCable (NameError)

and this error when I try to generate the chanel

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The generator error is because it's not available until Rails 5, so you would need to upgrade your app to use it.

As for user specific notifications, I recommend having a UserChannel and  leveraging the `stream_for` function, as it will create a channel for each user:

```
class UserChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_for current_user
  end
end
```

Then you can simply broadcast whatever notifications you want to each user as follows:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
UserChannel.broadcast_to(user, { notification: 'Test message' })
```